# certain fields get corrupted going from an Access report to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I can't make sense of this. I'm using Access 2003.

The problem occurs when I right-click an Access report, then click "Send..." which has only one option of "Mail recipient".  Then I click Excel.  An Outlook window containing an outgoing email opens with an Excel attachment.  There is one column with item ids.  Some get corrupted while others do not.  It seems they need to begin with the numerals 20 to get corrupted.  Anything else comes out OK.

For example, the following item ids are ok:

```
100657  
100657-17  
216116-115  
221007-001
```

The following get corrupted (the corrupted version follows):

```
202103-001 becomes 1313049  
205103-001 becomes 2408777
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Add the tag "Access" to your question to get it to a better audience.

Comment: I tried initially to add Access as a tag and it told me my reputation was too low to create a tag.  Access did not appear in the list of choices.  I looked again and it looks like it uses ms-access.  Thanks.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Until recently there used to be an `access` tag, but it appears to have been deleted. My guess is that it was just too ambiguous to be of any real value. The `ms-access` tag is the one that is going to get the most eyeballs for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the formatting of source, it is possible that 20's are getting corrupted to date formates.  This is particularly likely if the original source of the data being used by access is Excel.  You likely want to set the format to text, particularly if you are using numbers to track ID's like stock numbers.

Also check what, format is used in Access for the Field.  Excel is less likely to take liberties with your data when the Access field is set to text.  If you continue to have problems after addressing the formats. Post more details about the formats in your question.

Comment: The source is an Access table, and the field is defined as Text.  The original source is a SQL Server table defined as nvarchar(100) but I doubt that has any significance.  It doesn't look like the report has any property to indicate text.

Comment: I looked closer at the options for date conversions; 1313049 is Excel Julian for 1/1/5495, while 2408777 is excel Julian for 1/1/8495, so a single step that does not seem likely. If Excel was doing math on import 202103 - 001 would be 202102.  After Send if you go to word or CSV do you get the same results?

Comment: I just did some quick math and found something interesting.  2408777 - 1313049 = 1095728.  2051 - 2021 = 30 * 365.25 = 10957.5.  Coincidence?  So I think you are right about the date thing.  As soon as I get the vendor to get me all the objects I need to customize this report I will try to prefix the field in question with a space and if that doesn't work I'll try a control character.